Variation régionale de prononciation des consonnes finales?
En ce qui concerne certaines consonnes finales précédees d'une voyelle, il y a plusieurs mots dans lesquels la consonne se prononce ou non. Parmi eux figurent but, août et tandis dans la locution figée tandis que (voir la Banque de dépannage linguistique ici et ici).
Je me demande si le choix de les prononcer ou non varie en partie selon la région natale du locuteur. En effet, considérons la BDL susmentionnée : puisqu'elle est une ressource québécoise, dans quelle mesure ses renseignements sur cette question s'appliquent-ils aux prononciations hexagonales ?
Et si les dialectes régionaux n'expliquent pas du tout ce choix (consonnes prononcées ou muettes), existe-t-il d'autres facteurs qui l'expiquent outre la préférence personnelle?

Voir Ces prononciations qui divisent la France.
